# My if-else statements aren't doing the things that are in the second and third "else if"

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

Ignore the fact that the text is in swedish (if you can).

The problem is that when i run the program and i press "yes" on the first two questions that pop up, the first if statement works fine, but whenever i press, for example "yes" then "no", nothing happens, and i think it's because this else if statement is after the first if statement, so it's like skipping the ones after the first if statement,i would really appreciate some help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Slutuppgift extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Slutuppgift() {
    initComponents();
}                                       

    Object[] options = {"Osäker",
                "Nej",
                "Ja"};

int svar_1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är bilden tagen i europa? "
,
"Fråga 1",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null);



int svar_2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är det vatten med i bilden?"
,
"Fråga 2",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null);

 if (svar_1 == 1 && svar_2 == 1){
    int svar_3 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är platsen på bilden associerad med hasardspel?"
,
"Fråga 3",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null);   


if (svar_3 == 2)
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på Vita Huset");
}

else if (svar_3 == 1){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på Las Vegas");
}

else if (svar_3 == 0){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte inte på någon bild alls, du klickar bara på osäker");
}

else if (svar_1 == 2 && svar_2 == 1){
int svar_4 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är det mycket grönska på bilden?"
,
"Fråga 3",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null); 

if (svar_4 == 2){
    int svar_5 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Finns det moln på bilden?"
,
"Fråga 4",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null);

if(svar_5 == 2){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på Eiffeltornet");
}    
else if (svar_5 == 1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på lutande tornet i Pisa");
}
} 


else if (svar_1 == 1 && svar_2 == 2){
    int svar_6 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är platsen associerad med musik?"
,
"Fråga 3",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null); 
}    

else if (svar_1 == 2 && svar_2 == 2){
    int svar_7 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
"Är byggnaden gammal?"
,
"Fråga 3",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options, null); 

        int svar_6 = 0;

if (svar_7 == 2){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på Big Ben");
}

else if (svar_7 == 1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du tänkte på Turning Torso");
}


}                                        

private void bild1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   

}                                  

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Slutuppgift.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Slutuppgift.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Slutuppgift.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Slutuppgift.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Slutuppgift().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel bild1;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild2;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild3;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild4;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild5;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild6;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild7;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild8;
private javax.swing.JLabel bild9;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel välj;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *NOTE* the code isn't fully complete yet, but it should still be working, but it's not.

Comment: enumerating your variables makes code non-readable, poorly indenting the code is equally bad. In what scope is `options` and all the `svar`s.

Comment: Please properly format this code. Especially correct indentation would make it much easier to read.

Comment: i know that the code is horrible, i am new to programming and i dont know much terms in programming

Comment: if we ignore the code and i'll just explain what the problem is

Comment: My guess is that you assume an else if follows one if statement when it is really following another.  Always use brackets on if statements and it will be clear to those reading your code as well as yourself.

Comment: I have two main questions that i always ask when i run the program. Depending on what the user presses on the "yes" and "no" buttons, different questions should be asked

Comment: But this is not the case, because when i press "no" "no", it works fine, because that if statement is the first in the code, but when i try another combination, it doesn't do anything

Comment: @inneedofhelp If you need help with code that is not working as intended, then you have to show that code and not just talk about it. Code is precice, human speech is not. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @inneedofhelp A piece of advice.  Write the *simpler* program before you write the more complex one.  It will help you understand the problem if you write the shortest amount of code which still replicates the problem.

Comment: well, thanks for the help guys, i'm just gonna skip this one and kms now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of arranging the if Braces --> } <--.

Look to be a good debugger 
    First keep only one "if" and cut the other code (after backup your file).
    Test is it working as you plan or not.
    Second Past one more "if" with some code.
    Test is it ok also 
    AND SO ON.

By this way your skill will develop from a programmer to a developer my friend.
and keep working and keep tracking.